# Muting streams in Android

Tags: android, audio, stream, mute

I've built a small app that mutes/unmute the music stream using the class `AudioManager`.
In fact, it works until I close the application. i.e. I've muted the sream, I close the app, I restart the app and the button doesn't unmute the stream any more. I've searched in the net but no one seems to have met this problem.

Here's my code:

```
public class ControlloVolume extends Activity {
ToggleButton tb_mute;
Button btn_mute;
AudioManager mAudioManager;
boolean mute;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_controllo_volume);

    tb_mute = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tb_mute);
    btn_mute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mute);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if(mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)==0){
        mute = true;
        tb_mute.setChecked(mute);
    }else{
        mute = false;
        tb_mute.setChecked(mute);
    }

    }

public void onButtonClicked(View view){
    if(!mute){
        mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        tb_mute.setChecked(true);
        mute = true;
    }else{
        mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        tb_mute.setChecked(false);
        mute = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "close", do you mean that your app is destroyed or just put in the background? Does getStreamVolume return 0 when you restart the app?

Answer (score 0):

First, beware [it's not recommended](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

> For a better user experience, applications MUST unmute a muted stream
>   in onPause() and mute it again in onResume() if appropriate.

But I assume you know what you're doing, so here we go.

Note this line from the docs on [setStreamMute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

> The mute command is protected against client process death: if a
>   process with an active mute request on a stream dies, this stream will
>   be unmuted automatically.

I've checked on my device and indeed, when I just exit my activity, stream stays muted. But as soon as I kill the process, mute goes away.
Take a look at [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

As your current approach will not work reliably, you could write a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) which will trigger the mute - start that service from your activity.
Also you would likely need to [setStreamSolo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).

Two **important** things.

1. `Volume==0` and `muted` are NOT the same thing. I.e. stream can have volume==0 but be not muted. Though if stream *is* muted, volume will always be 0
2. mute requests are cumulative. I.e. if you've set mute twice, you must unmute twice as well - your code doesn't handle that

As a side note, for such app you would probably want to use widget instead of activity.

---

**Off topic.** It seems surprisingly lot of people don't quite get how booleans work.
And as I see code such as yours regulary, here is a bit streamlined rewrite.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... setup just like you did

    // boolean is just like any other type. You can assign not only
    // constants, but expressions too
    mute = (mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)==0);
    tb_mute.setChecked(mute);
}

public void onButtonClicked(View view){
    mute = !mute; // invert value
    mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mute);
    tb_mute.setChecked(mute);
}
```

Comment: Say, what about the new API of Android 6 (API 23) for adjustStreamVolume ? The "setStreamMute" is deprecated and it's suggested to use adjustStreamVolume . Does the auto-restore of volume still work for when the app is killed ? What has changed?

Comment: @androiddeveloper don't know, I have not touched Android for a year or so

Comment: nowadays it looks like this: mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0); for muting, and: mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0); for returning to normal