# Android how can I mute stream voice call compeletely?

Tags: android, stream, call, voice, mute

As the title suggests, I want to mute the sound before the call was connected. I set stream by below code:

```
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
```

and also try code:

```
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 0, 0);
```

It can make the sound at the lowest, but it is not silent. There is still a small sound. If I play another music this time, they will mix together. I don't want this suitation.

Do any one have any ideas to avoid this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: My guess is that Android doesn't allow this. If you try to turn it all the way down manually during a call, it also has a minimum volume (at least on my M8). Maybe you should ask yourself what you want to achieve by muting the sound, and if you could achieve this in other ways.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101624/muting-streams-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
val audioManager = getSystemService(AudioManager::class.java)
audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
        AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI, 0)
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
        AudioManager.ADJUST_TOGGLE_MUTE, 0)
audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This code from my mp3 player should help u to solve the issue.

```
phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                // String stateString = "N/A";

                Log.v(TAG, "Starting CallStateChange");
                switch (state) {

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();;        
                        isPausedInCall = true;

                    }

                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    // Phone idle. Start playing.

                    if (mp != null) {
                        if (isPausedInCall) {
                            isPausedInCall = false;
                            initNotification();
                            mp.start();
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                }

            }
        };

        // Register the listener with the telephony manager
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: actually, when I dial another person's phone, I don't want to hear any sound coming from the other one. At this time I would like to play a music from my phone instead of listening to the sound which coming from other one's phone. After the call connected, I will stop the music.